# Formik re-renders on react state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I'm using a custom component in formik field, and need to call a function upon text change inside function (in order to get all matching hints related to input)

```
 <Field
            id="assignees"
            name="assignees"
            component={({
              field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
              form, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
              ...props
            }) => {
              return (
                    <input
                      key="assignees"
                      className="input-fields"
                      placeholder="Type names of assignees to start getting suggestions"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        form.setFieldValue(field.name, e.target.value);
                        getMatching(field.value);
                      }}
                      {...props}
                      {...form}
                      //   {...field}
                    />
    );
}}
/>
```

The matching function that's being called in upper code is as below. It updates a state and that state is then being showed inside span in a formik field.

```
const getMatching = (keyword) => {
    for (const item of users) {
      if (keyword !== "" && item.name.startsWith(keyword)) {
        setMatching(item.name);
        return;
      } else {
        setMatching(undefined);
      }
    }
  };
```

**Expected Behaviour**
Formik input doesn't lose focus and retains all the input texts I added upon state change or rerender

**Actual Behaviour**
Input component loses focus and field is reset whenever a state is set by `getMatching` function

**EDIT- CODE SANDBOX LINK**
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-merkle-w191l

Comment: can you add your complete code in a sandbox ?

Comment: sure let me add

Comment: use render instead of component in `Field` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- no need to store `matching` in state, it can be derived from looking at the assignee textbox value and the list of users
- the assignee textbox (I'm calling it `searchAssignee`) and the list of selected assignees (`assignees`) are essentially two different inputs, so must be separate Formik inputs
- separating the two above inputs fixes the focus issue

The whole idea of formik is that it removes the need to store input values in state. I removed the unnecessary state and separated the above inputs.

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hofstadter-tsfwl?file=/src/App.js:2893-2896)

```
const getMatching = (users, keyword) => {
  if (!keyword) return null;
  const match = users.find(({ name }) => name.startsWith(keyword));
  if (!match) return null;
  return match.name;
};

const FormContainer = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        summary: "",
        description: "",
        searchAssignee: "",
        assignees: []
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className="textcolor">Summary</div>
            <Field
              id="summary"
              name="summary"
              placeholder="Add a short summary for your task"
              component={({
                field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
                form, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
                ...props
              }) => {
                return (
                  <input
                    className="input-fields"
                    {...props}
                    // {...form}
                    {...field}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className="textcolor">Description</div>
            <Field
              id="description"
              name="description"
              placeholder="Description"
              component={({
                field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
                form, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
                ...props
              }) => {
                return (
                  <ReactQuill
                    theme="snow"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={field.onChange(field.name)}
                    style={{ minHeight: "5rem" }}
                    {...field}
                    {...props}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className="textcolor">Assignees</div>
            <Col className="assignee-wrapper d-flex">
              <div className="d-flex">
                <Field
                  id="assignees"
                  name="assignees"
                  component={({
                    field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
                    form, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
                    ...props
                  }) => (
                    <>
                      {field.value.map((item) => (
                        <div
                          className="assignee-tag d-flex"
                          onClick={() => {
                            const newAssignees = field.value.filter(
                              (val) => val !== item
                            );
                            form.setFieldValue(field.name, newAssignees);
                          }}
                        >
                          <div>{item}</div>
                          <GrFormClose />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </>
                  )}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex col">
                <Field
                  id="searchAssignee"
                  name="searchAssignee"
                  placeholder="Type names of assignees to start getting suggestions"
                  component={({
                    field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
                    form, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
                    ...props
                  }) => {
                    const suggestion = getMatching(users, field.value);
                    return (
                      <>
                        <input
                          className="input-fields"
                          {...props}
                          {...form}
                          {...field}
                        />
                        {suggestion && (
                          <span
                            className="text-nowrap"
                            onClick={() => {
                              if (!form.values.assignees.includes(suggestion)) {
                                form.setFieldValue("assignees", [
                                  ...form.values.assignees,
                                  suggestion
                                ]);
                              }
                            }}
                          >
                            {suggestion}
                          </span>
                        )}
                      </>
                    );
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <div className="mt-2 float-end">
          <button className="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">
            Add
          </button>
          <button className="btn btn-light btn-sm ms-2" type="reset">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
};

const App = ({ isModalVisible, setModalVisible }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { name: "Hello World" },
    { name: "Foo Bar" }
  ]);

  return (
    <Modal show={true}>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Row>
          <div>
            <GrFormClose
              className="float-end"
              onClick={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <FormContainer
              users={users}
            />
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```